Understanding the proof of $L^{\infty}$ is complete.
I got lost when reading the proof of $L^{\infty}$ is complete. The book proceed the proof as follows:

We show that each absolutely convergent series in $L^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is convergent. We do this by considering functions (instead of equivalence classes) in $\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.
Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of functions that belong to $\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ and satisfy $\sum_k\|f_k\|<+\infty$. For each positive integer $k$, let $N_k=\{x\in X:|f_k(x)|>\|f_k\|_{\infty}\}$. Then the series $\sum_kf_k(x)$ converges at each $x$ outside $\bigcup_kN_k$, and the function $f$ defined by
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_kf_k(x)\quad&\text{if $x\notin\bigcup_kN_k$},\\
\\
0\quad&\text{if $x\in\bigcup_kN_k$}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
is bounded and $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Since $\bigcup_kN_k$ is locally $\mu$-null, the inequality
\begin{align*}
\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}\tag1
\end{align*}
holds for each $n$, and so
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty} = 0.\tag2
\end{align*}
Thus $L^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is complete.

I have a couple of questions about this proof.

The definition of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ says that the elements of $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ are equivalence classes of functions. Why is it legit to proceed the proof by considering functions in $\mathscr{L}^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$?

In the proof, it says "the series $\sum_kf_k(x)$ converges at each $x$ outside $\bigcup_kN_k$". Here is how I understand this step, and I want to know if it is correct?



If $x\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k$, then $|f_k(x)|\leq\|f_k\|_{\infty}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and thus the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}$ implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ converges by the comparison test.


The proof claims that $f$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. I couldn't see why this is true. I want to show that for each $t\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in X:f(x)<t\}\in\mathscr{A}$. But I honestly don't know how to do this. Can someone please help me out?

I got complete lost by inequality (1) and (2). Why does $\bigcup_kN_k$ being locally $\mu$-null imply that the inequality (1) holds for each $n$? Why can we just take limit for both side without proving the limits exist?


Please please help! I really appreciate it!

Note:$\quad$ The book I am reading defines $\|f\|_{\infty}$ to be the infimum of those nonnegative numbers $M$ such that $\{x\in X:|f(x)>M|\}$ is locally $\mu$-null.

Reference:$\quad$ Theorem 3.4.1 from Measure Theory by Donald Cohn


To answer this, the following statement is true:


Let $(f_n), (g_n)$ be two sequences in $L^p$ such that $f_n = g_n$ a.e, $f_n \rightarrow f$ a.e, then $g_n \rightarrow f$ a.e

Indeed, let $A_n = \{f_n \neq g_n\} \ \forall n, Cf = \{\lim_n f_n \neq f\}$ and set $$Cg = \left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \right) \cup Cf$$
Then $I$ has zero measure, and on $I^c$, the complement of $I$, $f_n = g_n \ \forall n, f_n \rightarrow f$. A simple argument will tell that $\lim_n g_n(x) = f(x) \ \forall x \in I^c$. Thus, $g_n \rightarrow f$ a.e
With this statement, the convergence property of a sequence in $L^p$ doesn't depend on the choice of equivalent classes of functions. If one choice of a sequence of functions that converges, every other choice that is equivalent to this sequence will also converge.

Your understanding in this step is correct.
Since the sum $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f_k(x)$ converges on $N^c$, where $N = \bigcup_k N_k$, the function $f$ can be written as follows:
$$
    f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} f_k(x) 1_{N^c}(x) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 1}^N f_k(x)1_{N_c}(x) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} g_N(x)
$$
where
$$
    g_N(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^N f_k(x)1_{N^c}(x)
$$

The function $g_N$ is the sum of $N$ measurable functions so it is measurable. The limit of $g_N$ is therefore also measurable.
4.
$$
    f - \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k = \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \cdot (1_{N^c} - 1) + \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}
$$
Thus,
$$
    \left\lVert f - \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \right\rVert \le \left\lVert \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \cdot (1_{N^c} - 1) \right\rVert + \left\lVert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \right\rVert
$$
Notice that the first norm is zero because the sum inside is zero a.e. Now, we want to show that
$$
     \left\lVert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \right\rVert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \rVert
$$
By definition, for each $N \in \mathbb{N}, N \ge n + 1$, and for every $x \in X$, we have
$$
    \left\vert \sum_{k = n + 1}^N f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \right\vert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^N \vert f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \vert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^N \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \rVert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}\rVert
$$
Now, let $N \rightarrow \infty$, since
$$
   \sum_{k = n + 1}^N f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \rightarrow \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x)
$$
we must have
$$
   \left\vert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \right\vert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}\rVert \hspace{0.5cm} (\color{red}{1})
$$
By definition of the norm, we have
$$
     \left\lVert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \right\rVert = \inf\left\{M : \left\{\left\vert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \right\vert > M\right\} \text{ is locally } \mu-\text{null} \right\}
$$
By $(\color{red}{1})$, the set
$$
   \left\{\left\vert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k(x) \cdot 1_{N^c}(x) \right\vert > \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}\rVert\right\}
$$
is an empty set, and thus is a (locally) $\mu$-null set. Therefore,
$$
    \left\lVert \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \right\rVert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}\rVert
$$
Finally, notice that
$$
   f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} = f_k \text{ a.e} \Longrightarrow \lVert f_k \cdot 1_{N^c} \rVert = \lVert f_k \rVert
$$
Thus,
$$
    \left\lVert f - \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \right\rVert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \rVert
$$
For the rest, since
$$
   0 \le \left\lVert f - \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \right\rVert \le \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \rVert
$$
and
$$
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = n + 1}^\infty \lVert f_k \rVert = 0
$$
the squeeze theorem implies the limit of $\left\lVert f - \sum_{k = 1}^n f_k \right\rVert$ exists and equals to $0$

Thank you very much! I have a question about a step in your answer to 4. After you get $$\left|\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\cdot1_{N^c}(x)\right|\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|f_k\cdot 1_{N^c}|,$$ you said by definition of the norm, we get $$\left|\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}f_k \cdot 1_{N^c}\right|\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|f_k\cdot1_{N^c}|.$$ Why is this true? I think by definition of the norm, what we can get is $$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\cdot1_{N^c}\right|\geq\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\cdot1_{N^c}(x)\right|$$ holds locally $\mu$-a.e., which doesn't imply the inequality.

@Beerus I've updated my answer for question 4

I really appreciate @ThànhNguyễn's answer! This answer post is for my own record with extra details worked out. If you find any mistakes, please comment below! Thanks a lot!

Let $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of functions belong to $\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}$ converges. For each positive integer $k$, define $N_k=\{x\in X:|f_k(x)|>\|f_k\|_{\infty}\}$. Then for $x\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k$, we have $\|f_k\|\geq|f_k(x)|$ for all $k$, and thus the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}$ implies the convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ by the comparison test. Define a function $f$ be letting
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\quad &\text{if}\ x\notin\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k,\\
\\
0\quad &\text{if}\ x\in\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then $f$ is clearly bounded. Write $f$ as
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\right)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\\
&= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\right)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(x),
\end{align*}
where $g_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}$. Since for each positive integer $k$ the function $f_k$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, $|f_k|$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, and so $N_k\in\mathscr{A}$. Thus if $t>1$, then $\left\{x\in X:\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}<t\right\}=X\in\mathscr{A}$; if $t\leq0$, then $\left\{x\in X:\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}<t\right\}=\emptyset\in\mathscr{A}$; if $0<t\leq1$, then $\left\{x\in X:\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}<t\right\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\in\mathscr{A}$. Hence $\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. As a result, $f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}$, and so $g_n$, is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable. Therefore, $f=\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n$ is $\mathscr{A}$-measurable, and $f\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$.


Note that
\begin{align*}
f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k &= \sum_{k=1}^nf_j\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - \sum_{k=1}^nf_k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right) + \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}.
\end{align*}
Thus
\begin{align*}
\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty}\leq\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right)\right\|_{\infty} + \left\|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}.\tag1
\end{align*}
Since $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k$ is locally $\mu$-null, $\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} = 1$ holds locally almost everywhere, and so $\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right)$ holds locally almost everywhere. Then the set $\left\{x\in X:\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right)\right|>0\right\}$ is locally $\mu$-null. Thus
\begin{align*}
&\left\|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right)\right\|_{\infty}\\
=\ &\inf\left\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+:\left\{x\in X:\left|\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\left(\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c} - 1\right)\right|>M\right\}\ \text{is locally $\mu$-null}\right\}\\
=\ &0.
\end{align*}
Now we want to show that
\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}.
\end{align*}
For each positive integer $m$ such that $m\geq n+1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^mf_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right| &\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right|.\tag2
\end{align*}
Note that the set
\begin{align*}
\left\{x\in X:\sum_{k=n+1}^m\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right| > \sum_{k=n+1}^m\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}\right\}
\end{align*}
is a subset of
\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{k=1}^m\left\{x\in X:\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right| > \left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}\right\},
\end{align*}
because for any $x$ not in the latter union it cannot belong to the former set, then the facts that union of locally $\mu$-null sets is locally $\mu$-null and that every subset of a locally $\mu$-null set is locally $\mu$-null imply that the former set is locally $\mu$-null, and thus for each positive integer $m$ such that $m\geq n+1$ the relation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n+1}^m\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
holds locally almost everywhere. Now inequality (2) together with the fact that $\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|\geq0$ imply that for each positive integer $m$ such that $m\geq n+1$ the inequality
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^mf_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}\tag3
\end{align*}
holds locally almost everywhere. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ converges for $x\in\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c$, we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}$ converges for all $x\in X$, and thus
\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\to\infty}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^m\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right|
\end{align*}
for all $x\in X$. We now prove
\begin{align*}
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty},\tag4
\end{align*}
holds locally almost everywhere. To see this, consider the points $x$ in $X$ such that inequality (3) holds. Assume to the contrary that (4) fails to hold for these points, then
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| > \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty} > \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right|.
$$
Note that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $m\geq N$ implies that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| - \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| < \epsilon.
$$
Now let
$$
\epsilon = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right| - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}.
$$
Then this would imply
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty} < \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}\left(f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right)\right|
$$
whenever $m\geq N$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, (4) holds wherever (3) holds, and so (4) holds locally almost everywhere. Now by the definition of $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$, we have
\begin{align*}
\left\|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty} = \inf\left\{M\in\mathbb{B}_+:\left\{x\in X:\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right|>M\right\}\ \text{is locally $\mu$-null}\right\}.
\end{align*}
But (4) implies that the set
$$
\left\{x\in X:\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right| > \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}\right\}
$$
is locally $\mu$-null. Therefore,
$$
\left\|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}.
$$


Note that $f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x) = f_k(x)$ holds locally almost everywhere. Then $\left\{x\in X:\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right|>M\right\}$ is locally $\mu$-null if and only if $\left\{x\in X:|f_k(x)|>M\right\}$ is locally $\mu$-null, according to the following lemma:

Lemma$\quad$ Let $f$ and $g$ be complex-valued functions on the measure space $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$. Let $M\in\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f(x)=g(x)$ holds locally almost everywhere. Then $|f(x)|\leq M$ holds locally almost everywhere if and only if $|g(x)|\leq M$ holds locally almost everywhere.
Proof$\quad$ Denote $E=\{x\in X:g(x)\neq f(x)\}$, $E_1=\{x\in X:|f(x)|>M\}$, and $E_2 = \{x\in X:|g(x)|>M\}$. Then $E$ is locally $\mu$-null. Suppose $E_1$ is locally $\mu$-null. If $x\in\left(E\bigcup E_1\right)^c$, then $g(x)=f(x)$ and $|f(x)|\leq M$, and thus $|g(x)|\leq M$, which implies $x\in E_2$. Thus, $E_2\subseteq\left(E\bigcup E_1\right)$. Scine the union of locally $\mu$-null sets is locally $\mu$-null and every subset of a locally $\mu$-null set is locally $\mu$-null, we have $E_2$ is locally $\mu$-null. Proof of the other direction is analogous.

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
&\left\|f_k\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}\right\|_{\infty}\\
=\ &\inf\left\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+:\left\{x\in X:\left|f_k(x)\chi_{\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}N_k\right)^c}(x)\right|>M\right\}\ \text{is locally $\mu$-null}\right\}\\
=\ &\inf\left\{M\in\mathbb{R}_+:\left\{x\in X:|f_k(x)|>M\right\}\ \text{is locally $\mu$-null}\right\}\\
=\ &\|f_k\|_{\infty}.
\end{align*}
Thus (1) implies that
$$
\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}
$$
holds for each positive integer $n$. Let $p_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}$. Since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}$ converges, we have that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\|f_k\|_{\infty} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}\right| = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty} < \epsilon.
$$
That is, for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a positive integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $p_n=|p_n-0|<\epsilon$, and thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty} = 0.
$$
Finally, since
$$
0\leq\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty}\leq\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\|f_k\|_{\infty}=0,
$$
the squeeze theorem implies that the limit of $\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty}$ exists and equals $0$. THE FOLLOWING ARGUMENT IS NOT CORRECT, OR AT LEAST NOT WHAT THE BOOK IS INTENDED TO SAY. PLEASE SEE THE UPDATE BELOW. Hence,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} = \left\|f-\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} = 0.
$$
Since $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is a norm on $L^p(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, it follows that
$$
f = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k \in \mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu).
$$
That is, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ converges. The proof is completed.


Update
After we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\|_{\infty} = 0$, we can conclude that $f\in\mathscr{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ is the limit of the sequence of sums $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^nf_k\right\}$; or equivalently, the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f_k$ converges.
